Jira : Obtener incidencias que no tengan comentarios
JQL para incidencias que no tengan comentarios.
Estoy intentando esto 'comment is EMPTY' y me arroja : "El campo 'comment' no soporta consultas de campos VACíOS"

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
